# how to get the REAL value of multiple checkbox?

Tags: php, checkbox, simplexml

I have a multiple checkbox in my html table with $number as index
    ">

I get the value of the multiple checkbox:

```
$checklist = $_POST['checkbox'];
```

The value of the $checklist are correct when i do echo.

```
$i = $checklist[0];
echo $i; // 2 for example
```

Now i try to get the node number $i (2) in my xml file

$participants = simplexml_load_file($fileName);
Then this line echo $participants->participant[$i]->name; display blank

Or if define $j = 2; then echo $participants->participant[$j]->name; display the name of the participant 3 ($j + 1) and that is correct.

That mean $check or $i = $checklist[0]; don't give a simple number like $j, any idea please ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: do a `var_dump($checklist)` to see which values you have received...

Comment: What do you mean by "REAL value"? when you post a form with checkboxes, if the checkbox is checked, whatever the value in the `value` attribute is what gets posted. So `<input type='checkbox' name='foo' value='bar'>` gets checked and posted, `$_POST['foo']` has the value of `bar`.

Comment: Just think I figured out the problem. The object list from simplexml is zero based. Meaning that the count starts with 0. Meaning that the third entry, is actual number 2 (`0, 1, 2`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is just because php type the variable, so $check is not int type, $j is int type.
Just do $i= (int)$check and it works well when doing $participants->participant[$i]->name;
Thansk for your participation.